# How to cause a test crash with kdump?

Tags: kernel, crash

After installing `linux-crashdump` and `kdump-tools` according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe and configuring the latter so that `cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded` prints `1`, I'm having trouble causing a test crash with

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

The system freezes and graphic errors occur in unity, but then nothing happens for 10 minutes (the wiki article referenced above states that there "should be some delay" depending on memory (16GB in my case), but it can't be so long, right?!). I expect a reboot and creation of dump in `/var/crash`.

Are there other assertions which should be checked besides `cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded`? I tested with 3.17-rc6 and 3.16.0-18-generic on Ubuntu 14.10-beta1 and 3.13.0-36-generic on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Infos:

```
$ uname -a
Linux richter-lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 3.17.0-031700rc6-generic #201409211935 SMP Sun Sep 21 23:37:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/default/kdump-tools | grep -Ev '(#.*$)|(^$)'
USE_KDUMP=1
KDUMP_COREDIR="/var/crash"
```

The following is present in `/var/crash/`, but it doesn't seem to be the result of crashdump in my opinion (besides the fact that the restart doesn't work):

```
$ ls /var/crash/
kexec_cmd                              _usr_bin_gnome-tweak-tool.1000.uploaded
nvidia-331.0.crash                     _usr_bin_meld.0.crash
nvidia-343.0.crash                     _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
_usr_bin_gnome-tweak-tool.1000.crash   _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.crash
_usr_bin_gnome-tweak-tool.1000.upload  _usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.0.crash
$ cat /var/crash/kexec_cmd
/sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc6-generic root=UUID=c5aaeaf4-f555-45ff-a4f8-185a3aeac543 ro quiet splash irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-031700rc6-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc6-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the freeze usually indicates improper reserved memory try to increase it 128M at a time

your crashkernel parameter in grub config would look like this:

384M-:256M

increase the 256M gradually

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, I just figure it out.

Here is what I did:

Use Kdump and a kernel you build, when building the kernel, pass a arg

"deb-pkg"(ubuntu) to 'make', that means "make -jN deb-pkg",

then install the packages and kdump(linux-crashdump),